# SQL Server: Compare values from two tables and list missing value

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a report that needs to display people who have not done certain training. I have a query that shows people's names and the raining they've done, and another query that shows the entire list of training.

Query #1:

```
select distinct a.ID, b.Name, b.Descript, b.Code
from Roster a
join SkillCheckOff b on b.Id = a.ID 
order by a.ID, b.Descript
```

Query #2:

```
select Descript, Code
from LookupTable 
where Type = 'TRTSkillCheckOff' 
order by Descript
```

Final result:

```
Name          Descript
-----------------------
John          Training A
Abbie         Training A
Mike          Training B
...
```

Basically, if the descript from query #2 is not found from query #1 for each user, the final query needs to display the name and the missing training. Please help.

---

Based on the answers provided, I think the below query comes close.

```
with roster as (
select ID
from Roster
), 
skills as (
select Descript, Code from LookupTable where Type = 'TRTSkillCheckOff'
)
select r.ID, s.Descript
from roster r cross join skills s
EXCEPT
select name, Descript
from  SkillCheckOff
```

I think using EXCEPT works here.

Comment: Look up `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the query with CTE and CROSS JOIN:

```
;WITH CTE_Table AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.ID
        ,B.Name
        ,B.Descript
    FROM
        Roster A
        INNER JOIN SkillCheckOff B ON B.ID = A.ID
)
,CTE_Lookup AS (
    SELECT 
        L.Name
        ,L.Descript
    FROM
        Lookup
    WHERE
        Type = 'TRTSkillCheckOff' 
)                 
SELECT 
    C.ID
    ,C.Name
    ,C.Descript
FROM 
    CTE_Table C
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Lookup L 
WHERE 
    L.Descript <> C.Descript
ORDER BY
    C.ID
    ,C.Descript
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return anything.

Comment: So all descripts in query1 there are also in query2

Comment: I also tested it

Comment: I appreciate it, but I tested it as well and did not get anything. For example, I have a user named Mike and he has only done 1 training out of 35. So the query should show me the 34 training names that he did not complete, but it did not.

Comment: I understand now. later I will modify the query as required

Comment: You can't have `L.Descript` equal to something else while also null at the same time.

Comment: Try again please and let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct a.ID, b.Name, b.Descript, b.Code
from Roster a
join SkillCheckOff b on b.Id = a.ID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select 1
    from LookupTable 
    where Type = 'TRTSkillCheckOff' AND Descript = b.Descript
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return anything.

Comment: @LucasC922 Doesn't return nothing mean everybody has done all training?

Comment: No, sir. There are a lot of people who have not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate all pairs from rosters and skills then match that against the check-off list:

```
with roster as (
    select ID, Name from Roster
), skills as (
    select Descript, Code from LookupTable where Type = 'TRTSkillCheckOff'
)
select r.Name, s.Descript
from roster r cross join skills s
    left outer join SkillCheckOff k on k.Id = r.Id and k.Code = s.Code
where k.Id is null
order by r.Name, s.Descript;
```

Comment: I think this is close, but the query just shows everyone with the list of every training available, including even the ones that they did.

Comment: @LucasC922 The `where k.Id is null` should eliminate the ones that were actually completed.

Comment: @LucasC922 Then I suspect there's something wrong with the join condition. Do the codes match up exactly?

Comment: I think rather than using JOIN, using EXCEPT works here. I have modified the query in my original question to show it.

Comment: @LucasC922 I looked at your query above. Do the ID and Name columns correspond? That could be the problem with the join. Yes, `except` in this case.